# How to formulate prior for Trust.optim

Tags: r

I'm going to do minimization using trust optimization from `trustOptim` package. My objective function looks like

```
z=x1*y1+x2*y2
```

Sample x1,x2,y1,y2 looks like

```
x1       x2     y1      y2
0.14    0.86    1.54    2.15
0.10    0.90    1.83    2.27
0.11    0.89    1.64    2.29
0.13    0.87    0.96    1.83
0.07    0.93    0.85    1.17
```

Can you please suggest me how to calculate prior for trust.optim()?

My Expected outcome is minimum value of `z` I'm going to use `trus.optim` function. In R documentation, function definition looks like

```
pt <- trust.optim(start, fn=obj_f,
                  gr = binary.grad,  
                  hs = binary.hess,
                  method = "Sparse",
                  control = list(
                      report.precision=1L,
                      function.scale.factor=-1
                  ),
                  data=binary, priors=priors
                  )
```

Comment: expected output?

Comment: @saisaran, updated in my first post